# this is url rewrite is not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i tried to create this url rule buts not working: i dont know why :(

orginal url

```
www.example.com/viewprofile.php?username=jhon
```

the desired friendly url is

```
www.example.com/user/jhon
```

this is my.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^username/([^/]*)$ /viewprofile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

thanks for helping!! :))

Comment: sorrry this deos work, but how come it cnt access the css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial where the author explain step by step how to do exactly what you are trying to do. See if it helps: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/06/15/how-to-generate-friendly-urls-with-htaccess-part-2/